# Separate analytics for each profile page within a single website

Tags: google-analytics, matomo

There are multiple profiles on my website and each user is managing his/her profile himself. I am trying to find the most efficient way to present analytics of each profile to its owner. Here are 3 ways I found:

1. Record each and every hit made on a profile page against that profile. This is not just count of hits, this requires to record IP, country, referrer, search terms etc. against each hit. This would require me to manage a huge database as there would be a lot of hits on each page. And a lots of processing on this database. Even if I have to de this, what database is recommended for such use?
2. Use Google Analytics on each page. But I am not sure that Google Analytics provide an API to fetch Analytics for individual pages.
3. Use some open source solution like piwik. Again I'm not sure if they provide per page analytics or not.

Please suggest the pros and cons of using each approach.

**Update:** More explanation - Think of it like a facebook page where each user can see hits on his page. What solution you'd suggest?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? I don't understand what you are doing or trying to do? What do you mean by "There are multiple profiles on my website"? What's the problem with recording every hit? What individual pages data you're looking for?

Comment: Think of it like a facebook page, where each page owner can see hits on his page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Piwik, you can create a site id for each user, because you are allowed unlimited site ids with Piwik. You can can use a tracker with that user siteid, so when your member logs in, they get data only on their pages. You might also want to look at using custom variables and use the Piwik API to filter data. 
Check here for info on multi-tracker: http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/#toc-multiple-piwik-trackers

Comment: Multisite would make things too complicated. Custom variables seems a good option. Thanks :-)